# Make a horizontal scroll UI in App Inventor like Whatsapp,Vine, or Cruchyroll?

Tags: android, jquery, scroll, app-inventor

I am trying to make a UI like Vine, Whatsapp, and Crunchyroll. Let me explain. Whatsapp has Calls, Chats, and Contacts. When one of these is clicked, the top of the app displaying Whatsapp, Calls, Chats, and Contacts remains, while the middle displaying the content scrolls horizontally.The other two apps do the same.

Is there a way to do this in **App Inventor** or to design it in a different program and import it to app inventor?

Comment: see [these threads in the App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/horizontal$20scroll%7Csort:date) for workarounds

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to build your app in Android Studio? The thing that you want to do it's calling Action Bar. It's quite simple to do it in Android Studio, the App Inventor is good for educational proposes but it has it's own limits.

Android tutorial for beginners, Action Bar:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BOE9TeUY1w

Or try this one, which is for App Inventor:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X15CVi9n6OY

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to create is known as TabBar in Android. While there is no Tab component in AI2, you can use buttons to achieve similar effect.

Here's a [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mitappinventortest/WFiK3sFcDYE) which might help you to do so.